# markaby: using variable as class id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using markaby for the first time and would like to use a variable as a class id. Something along the lines of ...

```
mab = Markaby::Builder.new
val = 1
id_name = "this_id-#{val}"
mab.p.id_name!, "Hello world"
```

This, of course, yields

```
<p id=name>Hello world</p>
```

and what I am hoping for is

```
<p id=this_id-1>Hello world</p>
```

How does one go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `tag!` method like this:

```
id_name = "this_id-#{val}"
mab.tag! :p, :id => id_name do
    "Hello World"
end
```